# floating-point operations with bash

Tags: string, bash, replace, exif, operation

how can I transform the string "620/100" into "6.2" in a bash script

The context of my question is about image processing. EXIF data are coding the focal length in fractional format, while I need the corresponding decimal string.

Thanks for helping, Olivier

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `bc -l`

```
bc -l <<< "scale=2; 620/100"
6.20
```

OR awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f\n", (620/100)}'
6.20
```

Answer (score 6):

`bash` doesn't support floating point.

You could use `bc`:

```
$ echo "50/10" | bc -l
5.00000000000000000000
$ echo "scale=1; 50/10" | bc -l
5.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank-you for the answers. bc was what I needed.

I dont know if posting the result is of any use. Anyway, this the final piece of code for exteracting the focal length of a photo and print it in decimal format. It is supposed to work for all cameras. Tested on 4 cameras of 3 different brands.

```
F="your_image.JPG"
EXIF=$(exiv2 -p v "$F")
FocalFractional=$( echo "$EXIF" | grep -E '[^ ]*  *Photo *FocalLength '| grep -iohE "[^ ]* *$" )
Formula="scale=2; "$FocalFractional
FocalDecimal=$( bc -l <<< "$Formula" )
echo $ FocalDecimal
```

Answer (score 1):

bc -l <<< 100/3 really helped me also. Thanks a lot.
But if someone have to use variables to perform decimal arithmetic and the result has to be saved in a new variable, then try the below syntax:
answer=$(bc -l <<< $num_1*$num_2)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33920122)

Comment: This type of commentary is better provided as a comment on the question or answer that you are responding to, rather than as an answer itself.